# $G/G^{(1)}$ acts by conjugation on $G^{(1)}/G^{(2)}$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group, let $G^{(1)}:=[G,G]$ be its commutator subgroup and let $G^{(2)} :=[G^{(1)},G^{(1)}]$. I have read in a book that group-theoretic conjugation, understood as an action of $G$ on $G$ induces an action of $G/G^{(1)}$ on $G^{(1)}/G^{(2)}$.

Can someone explain me why is this? If $\bar{x} \in G/G^{(1)}$ and $[aba^{-1}b^{-1}] \in G^{(1)}/G^{(2)}$ then $$ \bar{x} \cdot [aba^{-1}b^{-1}] = [xaba^{-1}b^{-1}x^{-1}] $$ and I don't even see this is an element of $G^{(1)}$.

The book in question is Lickorish' *An Introduction to Knot Theory*, page 116.

Comment: Conjugation means your group action is $$x \mapsto x \ast x^{-1}$$ just show that it does not depend on the représentant in $G$ of $G/G^{(1)}$

Comment: Sure but my question is more elementary, I do not see that an element of the commutator subgroup of G conjugated by an element of G is an element of the commutator subgroup. That is, why is $[xaba^{-1}b^{-1}x^{-1}]$ an element of $G^{(1)}/G^{(2)}$?

Comment: Now $[a,b]=a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$, so $x^{-1}[a,b]x=[x^{-1}ax,x^{-1}bx]$.

Comment: @NickyHekster Okay, that's precisely what I couldn't see. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The (left) conjugation action ${}^gx:=gxg^{-1}$ intertwines the commutator, i.e. $ {}^g[a,b]=[{}^ga,{}^gb]$ (and same with the right conjugation action, regardless of which definition for $[a,b]$ used).

Indeed, if $w(a,b,\cdots)$ is any [word function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(group_theory)#:%7E:text=Article%20Talk,or%20even%20in%20every%20group.) (product of integer powers of the arguments) and $\phi$ is any homomorphism (with the same domain as $w$'s arguments), then

$$\phi(w(a,b,\cdots))=w(\phi(a),\phi(b),\cdots)$$ Good exercise. This applies of course with $\phi_g(x)={}^gx$ and $w(a,b)=[a,b]=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$.